# Is there a way to define event order pattern other than timestamp?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am building an event driven based application. It has 3 services to process order requests which send events to Kafka `order` topic. And 2 are producers and 1 is consumer.

- `producer-1`:  it sends `order.requested` event to `order` topic
- `producer-2`:  it sends `order.initiated` event to `order` topic
- `consumer-1`:  it consume both `order.requested` and `order.initiated` events from the `order` topic.

Each order has an order id which is partition key used in the topic. So all order events with the same `order id` will be in the same partition. However, the two events `order.requested` and `order.initiated` may come to the topic in any order. The `consumer-1` needs to see `requested` event before `initiated` for the same order.

How can I let Kafka topic to deliver `order.requested` event to the consumer before `order.initiated` event even the `order.initiated` comes to the topic earlier than `order.requested`?